# c# how to catch exception and resume execution

Tags: c#, exception

Good day!

i write simple console program. It have func Main () and class Adapter;

some simple code that explains how it works:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Work(array);
        //subcribing at some events;
        Application.Run();  
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //write to log;
    }
}
class Adapter
{
    ....
    public void GetSomething()
    {
        try
        {
            ...some work and exception goes here;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //catch exception and do Work:
            Work(array);
        }
    }
}
```

When exception goes- it catches at GetSomething. So,i write some values.But i need that the program still running after exception.
    But after catch in GetSomething method it goes to Exception ex at Main func and program exits;

How to do that program will still running after catch exception in GetSomething method?
Thank you!

Comment: the program is still running...

Comment: Unless you rethrown; that exception *was* dealt with. Your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: I don't think the program is exiting like you think it is.

Comment: perhaps you should set a boolean or int in the exception and move the `Work(array)` method outside of there change it's signature to return a boolean or int and then after it runs check the value..if it's true..then resume or if int = some value > 0 then resume.. does this make since..? and if `Work` is  method what does it look like..? show that code please

Comment: Calling `Work()` from inside the exception handler is probably a *very bad idea*.  Exception handling blocks should *only* handle the exception, they shouldn't perform business logic in response to the state of that exception.  Consider what would happen if another exception is thrown from inside an exception handling block before the code has fully handled it, the original exception would be lost.  Just handle the exception in the `catch` block, don't treat it like an `else` statement for doing further business operations.

Comment: "Just handle the exception in the catch block, don't treat it like an else statement for doing further business operations".What do you mean? What should i do?Just log it? But i need to do some business operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If what you want is to catch an exception and continue execution at the point of failure (which might be several layers down in the call stack) and possibly retrying the failed statement, you're pretty much out of luck.

Once your `catch` clause is invoked, the stack has been unwound up to that point. You can deal with the exception in some way and then choose zero or one of

- Continuing the exceptio via `throw ;`
- Re-throwing the exception via `throw e;`
- Throwing a new exception via `throw new SomeException();`

If didn't choose one of the above, execution continues at the point following the `try/catch/finally` block. For example:

```
    try
    {
      DoSomethingThatMightThrowAnException() ;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {

      DoSomethingToHandleTheExceptionHere() ;

      // Then, choose zero or one of the following:
      throw                  ; // current exception is continue with original stack trace
      throw e                ; // current exception is re-thrown with new stack trace originating here
      throw new Exception()  ; // a new exception is thrown with its stack trace originating here
      throw new Exception(e) ; // a new exception is thrown as above, with the original exception as the inner exception

    }
    finally
    {
       // regardless of whether or not an exception was thrown,
       // code in the finally block is always executed after the try
       // (and the catch block, if it was invoked)
    }

    // if you didn't throw, execution continues at this point.
```

If you don't do one of the above, execution continues at the statement following the `try/catch/finally` block.

The best you can do as far as retrying is something like this:

```
// retry operation at most 3
int number_of_retries = 5 ;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < number_of_retries ; ++i )
{
  try
  {

     DoSomethingThatMightThrowAnException() ;

     break ; // exit the loop on success

  }
  catch( Exception e )
  {

     Log.Error("well...that didn't work") ;

     ExecuteRecoveryCode() ;

  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is not possible in .NET. When an exception is thrown, control exits the current point and continues onto the first `catch` statement it can find in the call stack, or exits the program, thus eliminating execution of the call stack up to that point. This is part of the definition of exceptional behavior.

You can instead break down the process being done by `Work` and process each item one at a time to enable the same effect as what you're asking. In other words, instead of `Work(array)`, try

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    try { WorkSingle(item); }
    catch { continue; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use try, catch and finally:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/finally

http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dszsf989.aspx